# Are "elegir" and "escoger" cognates? If so, how did it happen?

Tags: etimología, sinónimos, latín

According to etimologias.dechile.net, it looks like ***elegir*** and ***escoger*** might be [cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate), they seem to have the very same Latin origin. However, the entries are quite laconic and I'd like to know more.

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?elegir:

> **escoger** está formada con raíces latinas... sus componentes léxicos son: *ex-* (hacia fuera), *con* (todo, junto) y *legere* (escoger, elegir, leer).

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?escoger:

> **elegir** proviene del latín eligere ... *e-*/*ex-* (de, desde, de entre) y *legere* (escoger, leer).

Are *elegir* and *escoger* really [cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate)? If so, is it known how they evolved into two different words? Do we know more about the history of the two words? How happened that they were imported twice (a *vulgarismo*/*cultismo* pair?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *escoger* and *elegir* are cognates.

*Elegir* comes from Latin *[ēligere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eligo#Latin)*, from *ex-* (“out of, from”) +‎ *leg-* (“choose, select, appoint”). Note that *ex-* changes to long *ē-* before the following consonant already in Latin, as it also happens e.g. in *eludir* (from *ēlūdere* < *ex-* + *lūdere*). The shifts in Latin between *e* and *i* in the root are probably (I'm no Latinist) a kind of [Ablaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut). The irregularity of *elegir* (*el**i**jo* vs. *el**e**gimos*, *el**i**gió* vs. *el**e**gía*, etc.) is more recently evolved.

*Escoger* comes from the same exact morphemes plus the prefix *con-*. In Latin there was already *colligere* (“bring together, gather, collect”), from *con-* + *leg-* (note the assimilation of *-nl-* to *-ll-*), which in Spanish gives us a [doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)):

- the learned form *colegir* (“gather, understand”) and
- the vernacular form *coger* (“take, grasp, grab”, from something like *[kol:i'jer] > *[kol'jer] > *[ko'ʎer] > *[ko'ʒer]; [ʒ] was then merged with [ʃ] and velarized to [x]).

(also, of course, *colegio*, which means both “school” and “association, professional body”).

From *colligere* derives the (unattested) Vulgar Latin **excolligere*, whence finally Spanish *escoger* with (irregular, but rather common) simplification of *x* /ks/ to /s/.

The variation between *-er* and *-ir* between these two verbs is a matter of chance; there were many Latin verbs originally in one class that ended up in the other as the system was reorganized.

By the way: the synonym *seleccionar* (from *selecto*) also comes from this root: *sēlēctum* is the supine of *sēligere*, from *sē-* (“without; apart, aside”) + *leg-* (meaning “to choose out”); the prefix *sē-* is the same as in *separar* and *seducir*.

Comment: Seleccionar as yet another cognate is a surprise for me! I am still not sure: which of them are *vulgarismo* and which *cultismo*? Can you also describe the reason behind the triple import, if all of them (now) carry the same meaning?

Comment: I'd say both *escoger* and *elegir* are normally evolved, so *vulgarismos*, but at least in my area *escoger* is unheard of except in formal registers. The rest comes down to variety and subtleties of meaning.

Comment: cult and vulgar are not accurate here. You mean: the "cultured" (Greek and Latin) and vernacular forms.

Comment: @Lambie From what I've read the preferred terms seem to be "learned" vs. "vernacular". I've taken the opportunity to add a link to the very interesting article about [doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)) in Wikipedia. Thanks for your corrections!

Comment: "Tienen un lenguaje culto" is not learned, It is educated. Though culto *can mean* learned sometimes. Learned is very literary.